# IIS Web request to different service based on incoming IP address?

Tags: iis

Can IIS be configured to direct a web request to different page based on the incoming connection's IP address?

I have devices connect to an .aspx page by going to a URL that looks like:

```
http://myhost/myservice/mypage.aspx
```

Depending on the inbound IP address, I would like to configure IIS to direct communications to a URL like:

```
http://myhost/myservice2/mypage.aspx
```

I do not want my back-end code to have any logic to check the IP addresses. I would like to configure IIS to manage this.  Is this possible?